# can i use class and classless qdisc together while using EDT(mq-fq)

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, tc

i just want to classify tcp and udp packet with filter
while using EDT(mq-fq with clsact(direct-action bpf))

because of implement of EDT
for using skb->tstamp as packet departure time,
fq qdisc will be must used

and its because of classless qdisc,
i cant use other class qdisc like htb together with it

i want to use EDT for TCP packets, 
andmake class for classification like htb for UDP packets

how can i use them together,
and attach filter for classify tcp,udp packets to fq and htb

Comment: oh also i already checked that mq can have fq, htb get together but i cant attach filter to mq qdisc for classify packet to each tcp-fq, udp-htb qdisc